# Как узнать Master или Slave?

Tags: mysql

Как проверить если щас БД работает в режиме Master или Slave?

Comment: Вас интересуют права или возможность подключиться?

Comment: есть база master, и есть база slave, при подключений к slave нужно не выполнять запросы которые пишут данные, поэтому наверное меня интересуют права

Comment: Тогда вас интересуют не права а статус сервера =) мастер\слейв...

Comment: а статус как получать?

Comment: Пониятия не имею, но подозреваю что достоверно никак ибо есть сихнорнизация мастер<->мастер, как тогда поступать?)) я всегда просто храню список мастеров и список слейвов =) а мой класс для работы с бд сам разруливает куда направлять запросы =)

Comment: кстати да, проверил кое что, вот такой запрос возвращает 0 записей на слейве =) SHOW MASTER STATUS;

Comment: можете добавить ответ? (хочу отметить решением)

Comment: было сделано ...

Answer (score 1):

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS;
```

выполненный на слейве вернёт 0 записей, на мастере - отличное от нуля число записей.